# Django internationalization minimal example

Tags: django

I'm having difficulty in internationalizing my app, so I present here a minimal example where my implementation fails.

Consider the following steps for producing a website in django with international support:

go to your favorite folder in the terminal and:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
cd mysite/
mkdir locale
python manage.py startapp main
# (1) modify mysite/urls.py
# (2) modify main/views.py
# (3) modify mysite/settings.py
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
# (4) modify locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
django-admin.py compilemessages -l de
python manage.py runserver
```

where:

```
## (1) mysite/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'main.views.home'),
)

## (2) main/views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse(_('Hello'))

## (3) mysite/settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'

from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + \
     ('django.core.context_processors.i18n',) # ensures all django processors are used.

## (4) locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
#: main/views.py:6
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "Hallo"
```

I assume the website has one *and only one* language, thus, I didn't activated the middleware locale by [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference):

> If you want to let each individual user specify which language he or
>   she prefers, use LocaleMiddleware. LocaleMiddleware enables language
>   selection based on data from the request. It customizes content for
>   each user.

This implementation does not produce the desired translation of "Hello" to "Hallo". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you access the Django admin panel, is it in German?
Did you try to set `LOCALE_PATHS`?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths

Comment: @andrea.ge: from what I understood from django documentation, these should be the minimal steps to translation... I tried LOCAL_PATHS, with no success, and I didn't tried admin because it requires a DB, which I'm not using...

Comment: To which path did you set `LOCALE_PATHS`?

Comment: LOCALE_PATHS = ('/Users/username/Desktop/Trials/test-django/mysite/locale'), which is the one the content of makemessages go to.

Comment: can you try:
LOCALE_PATHS = ('/Users/username/Desktop/Trials/test-django/mysite/locale', )
(notice the comma at the end)
and also check whether you have /Users/username/Desktop/Trials/test-django/mysite/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo ?

Comment: pff, with the comma it works... dam subtlety. Can you post an answer with the explanation on why I have to set locale_paths and use the comma, so I can accept it?

Comment: a=('something') => type(a) = <type 'str'>
wasted time on it as well the first time :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django collects translations in these 3 ways explained here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations

> The directories listed in LOCALE_PATHS have the highest precedence, with the ones appearing first having higher precedence than the ones appearing later.
>
> Then, it looks for and uses if it exists a locale directory in each of the installed apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS. The ones appearing first have higher precedence than the ones appearing later.
>
> Finally, the Django-provided base translation in django/conf/locale is used as a fallback.

Since your translation file is in none of these places you need to set it manually using `LOCALE_PATHS` as explained here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOCALE_PATHS

Comment: this is what fixed it for me: in settings.py add LOCALE_PATHS = (   '/mysite/locale', )

Answer (score 27):

1º Enable Internationalization in settings.py:

```
USE_I18N = True
```

2º On settings, import:

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

3º Set the languages that you are going to use in settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('pt-br', _('Portuguese')),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)
```

3º Configure the LOCALE_PATH in settings.py too:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'conf/locale'),
)
```

4º Inside the path you configured in LOCALE_PATH create the folders, ex:

```
$ cd django_project_folder
$ mkdir conf
$ mkdir conf/locale
```

5º Run the command:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -a
```

It will create a file .po inside a subfolder of each language set in settings.py LANGUAGES. Make the translations of each sentence inside the file.

Ps: Runs over the entire source tree of the current directory and pulls out all strings marked for translation.

For test, before run, put the tag

```
{% trans "Welcome to my project!" %}
```

inside your index.html and run the command makemessages again. You'll see inside de .po files a new string:

```
msgid "Welcome to my Project"
msgstr ""
```

6º Now, run the command:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

It will collect all msgstr from .po file and will compile in a .mo file

7º Run the project and test

8ª Plus: If you want that in URL show what language the user is using you can configure your url.py to show that:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    # your urls here,
)
```

Comment: After adding url pattern in urls.py it start showing page not found error.

Comment: Same problem for me. I opened [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502117/url-rendered-as-home-page-after-internationalization)