# Django internationalization convert in views

Tags: python, django

In the following code how can i convert the given text to the hindi language-hi..What are the parameters that i need to specify to convert to a language from the views..
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    output = _("Welcome to my site.")
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: Please, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16773455/2802003). It is usefull for this issue.

Comment: Internationalization and internalization are very different things! Almost opposites.