# Django Internationalization - Gettext error

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n, makemessages

Am building a site with Django. After downloading gettext-0.19.8.tar.gz ---> /Users/cohen/Downloads/gettext-0.19.8 and running all of the steps ./configure make and sudo make installation I received this error during it's installation below:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l en
```

Everything ran smoothly with the Gettext part until the instalation.
I am using a MAC, using Pycharm as my IDE.
Please advise!

PS there is a way to bipass the gettext instalation in order to make the messages?

Thank you!

```
xgettext: ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg/pip/_vendor/webencodings/__init__.py:1: Unknown encoding "utf8". Proceeding with ASCII instead.
xgettext: Non-ASCII string at ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg/pip/_vendor/webencodings/__init__.py:64.
          Please specify the source encoding through --from-code or through a comment
          as specified in http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html.
```

Why i got this error. I can't do the proper translation with this command

I followed this training:
[Django internationalization minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768809/django-internationalization-minimal-example)

http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones

https://gist.github.com/mbillard/1647940

LATER EDIT:
After reinstalling gettext in the virtualenv i got this error:

```
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ../build-aux/install-sh -c -d '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/gettext/share/doc/gettext/examples/build-aux'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../build-aux/javacomp.sh.in ../build-aux/javaexec.sh.in ../build-aux/csharpcomp.sh.in ../build-aux/csharpexec.sh.in '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/gettext/share/doc/gettext/examples/build-aux'
 ../build-aux/install-sh -c -d '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/gettext/share/gettext'
 /usr/bin/install -c ../build-aux/config.rpath '/Users/cohen/PycharmProjects/gettext/share/gettext'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
```

And the make check results:
Testsuite summary for gettext-tools 0.19.8

```
> ============================================================================
> # TOTAL: 198
> # PASS:  187
> # SKIP:  10
> # XFAIL: 0
> # FAIL:  1
> # XPASS: 0
> # ERROR: 0
> ============================================================================ See gnulib-tests/test-suite.log Please report to
> bug-gnu-gettext@gnu.org
> ============================================================================ make[7]: *** [test-suite.log] Error 1 make[6]: *** [check-TESTS] Error
> 2 make[5]: *** [check-am] Error 2 make[4]: *** [check-recursive] Error
> 1 make[3]: *** [check] Error 2 make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1 make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix this bug, you have to edit the files that have the error. In my case I entered into the files from my venv `/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg/pip/_vendor/webencodings/__init__.py` and edit 3 files

1.**init**.py
2. tests.py
3.x_user_defined.py

in their head I changed the string

> utf8

into

> utf-8.

This helped me to create the messages in Pycharm.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building it for yourself, I would rather install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) - it makes things easier to maintain in the long run:

```
brew install gettext
```

If it complains something like

> Warning: gettext is keg-only and must be linked with --force

you need to run

```
brew link gettext --force
```

and then it should work fine. (If it still doesn't, rebuild the virtualenv.)

Answer (score 0):

Just open file `./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg/pip/_vendor/webencodings/__init__.py` and change "utf8" to "utf-8" on the 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command with `--ignore venv` or `-i venv` ignoring virtual environment (venv in your case) as shown below, then the error is solved. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370035/django-makemessages-errors-unknown-encoding-utf8/76668362#76668362) explaining why the error occurs in detail:

```
python manage.py makemessages --ignore en venv
```

```
python manage.py makemessages -i en venv
```

The commands below also work:

```
django-admin makemessages --ignore en venv
```

```
django-admin makemessages -i en venv
```